# How to get default value of the SelectOption

Tags: lightning-aura-components

component: After loading the page,aircraft manufacture set to "all", If I change the "aircraft value to some other value, iam getting that value in javascript,if i change to "all" Iam getting null value..

```
  <aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="S360_DocumentFilterController" access="global">
<!-- Attribute defination -->
<aura:attribute name="objInfo" type="Document__c" default="{sobjectType : 'Document__c'}" />
<aura:attribute name="lstOfRecordType" type="String[]" />
<aura:attribute name="DocumentList" type="Document__c[]" />
<aura:attribute name="relateddate" type="String[]" default="Last Week,Last Month,Last Year"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
    <div class="slds-col">
        <span>
            <div class="slds-form-element">
                <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="select-01">Aircraft Manufacturer</label>

                <div class="slds-select_container">
                    <ui:inputSelect aura:id="Aircraft Manufacturer" class="slds-select" change="{!c.FindAllChanges}"/>
                    <ui:inputSelectOption text="all"/>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </span>
    </div>
```

---

```
 ({
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.Displayaircraftmanufacturer(component, 'Aircraft_Manufacturer__c', 'Aircraft Manufacturer');
    helper.DisplaydocumentRecordType(component,event,helper);
},
FindAllChanges:function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.FindAll(component, event, helper);
}
```

})

---

```
 ({
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.Displayaircraftmanufacturer(component, 
 'Aircraft_Manufacturer__c', 'Aircraft Manufacturer');
    helper.DisplaydocumentRecordType(component,event,helper);

},
FindAllChanges:function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.FindAll(component, event, helper);
} })
```

---

```
     ({
   Displayaircraftmanufacturer : function(component, fieldName,elementId )  {
    var action = component.get("c.getselectOptions");
    action.setParams({
        "objObject": component.get("v.objInfo"),
        "fld": fieldName
    });
    var opts = [];
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        if (response.getState() == "SUCCESS") {

            var allValues = response.getReturnValue();

            if (allValues != undefined && allValues.length > 0) {
                opts.push({

                    label: "All",
                    value: ""
                });
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < allValues.length; i++) {
                opts.push({

                    label: allValues[i],
                    value: allValues[i]
                });
            }

            component.find(elementId).set("v.options", opts);

        }

    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

FindAll:function(component, event, helper) {
    component.get("v.DocumentList",'');
    var action = component.get("c.findAll");
    var aircraft=component.find("Aircraft Manufacturer").get("v.value");
    alert('aircraft::::::::::'+aircraft);
    var recordType=component.find("recordTypeid").get("v.value");
    alert(aircraft);
    alert(recordType);

    action.setParams({
        "aircraftvalue":aircraft,
        "recordTypeLabel":recordType

    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state=response.getState();
       // alert('---->'+state); 
        if(state=='SUCCESS'){
            var result = response.getReturnValue();
            //alert('------->'+response.getReturnValue().sObjectProperties);
            component.set("v.DocumentList",response.getReturnValue().sObjectProperties);
        }

    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Comment: Please add information to your question like what you are trying to achieve and what error you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using lightning:select

```
<lightning:select aura:id="recordTypeid" name="recordTypeid" label="Record Types"  onchange="{!c.onRecordTypeChange}">
        <option value="All">ALL</option>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.lstOfRecordType}" var="Document">
            <option value="{!Document}"> {!Document}</option>
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:select>

onRecordTypeChange : function(component, event, helper) {
    // Print out the selected value
    var selected = component.find("recordTypeid").get("v.value");
    console.log('@@@@@@@: ' + selected);
}
```

Your code might look something like this